# Как правильно сократить такое присвоение?

Tags: laravel

```
        $profile_id = $user->id;
        $profile = new Profile();
        $profile->user_id = $profile_id;
        $profile->save();
```

Данное присвоение и потом дальнейшее сохранение происходит в контроллере фреймворка laravel 5.4 Может кто-то подскажет как правильнее такое делать.

Спасибо.

Comment: Profile::create(["user_id'=>$user->id])

Answer (score 0):

В моделе Profile:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

В контроллере:

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->user()->associate($user);
$profile->save();
```